# Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\ProjectCollaboratorsController::update() in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am going to update My permission values (`table name also permission`) this is My edit function regarding permission

```
public function edit($project,$id)
 {

   $projectId=Project::findOrFail($project, ['id'])->id;
   $permissions = Permission::permissioneditt($id,$projectId)->get();
 view('collaborators.permissionedit')->withPermissions($permissions);
     return view('collaborators.permissionedit', compact('permissions', 'projectId','collaborator->user()->first()->id'));

}
```

update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $projectId, $collaboratorId)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
            'status'  => 'required',
        ]);

        DB::table('permissions')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)
            ->update(['status' => $request->input('status')]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Permission has been updated successfully');

}
```

this is update form(`permission.edit.php`)

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.permission', $projectId) }}">
```

and routes is

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/permission',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update',]);
```

but generated following error

> ErrorException in ProjectCollaboratorsController.php line 268: Missing
>   argument 3 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\ProjectCollaboratorsController::update()

permission model scope is

```
 public function scopePermissioneditt($query, $id, $projectId)
    {
        return $query->where('collaborator_id',$id)->where('project_id',$projectId);//->exists();

    }
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/permission' [
    'uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update'
]);
```

Which essentially passes only one parameter to your `update` method, but in your controller it specifically requests two:

```
public function update(Request $request, $projectId, $collaboratorId)
{
   // ...
}
```

Therefore your route can be accessed, but the Controller tasked with resolving it will always fail because of a flaw in the route design.

How to fix? Hard to say without more code details, but if you remove the requirement of `$collaboratorId` variable from the `update` method you won't see the error anymore. The question then would be how to access the `$collaboratorId` inside that method. You could pass it along with the form, or redo the route so that it contains the collaborator id along with the project id. This second option seems more consistent with what you currently have in your `edit` route.

Comment: OK, thanks finally got solutions. I remove $collaborationId from update and remove ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId) also. then got sucess